# After baking the cloth simulation my object goes crazy anywhere

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

After baking my cloth simulation with pressure on it, it goes crazy and disappears from my viewport. The scene is simple, just an sphere subdivided five times with cloth modifier, and a plane with collision.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just deleted the bake and baked it again. It works now. https://blend-exchange.com/b/QesmpsKG

Comment: Look it again, if I extend the duration of the simulation (keyframes) this happens, I attached a GIF and also updated the blend file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's happening exactly but if you increase the *Quality Steps* it will work fine:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Even with 10 Quality Steps, doesn't work. Still is broken, it happens when the sphere touches the plane

Comment: See my edit, it works fine for me, don't forget to delete your previous bake of course

Comment: This is weird but after "Delete All Bakes" and bake again, it worked. I don't understand why this happen. Thank you